# Column vectors alignment

Tags: errors, alignment

I am trying to reproduce the column vectors in the figure

[image]

but I have problems in aligning them.
Is there anybody who could help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.
Could you please precise what alignement you are referring to ?

Comment: I am just able to write the first column vector with \begin{bmatrix}. I don't know how to put more vectors aligned and how to write x = column vector

Comment: You can add as much math as you want so basically, you can do `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}` multiple times in the same math environment say `$...$`. Once again, what alignment is problematic ?

Comment: The vertical so put a vector next to the other

Comment: if I use \begin{bmatrix} I obtain the first vector. But I want to put on his left the "d = vector" and on the right the other vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not very sure what your problem is. However, here is an example of what you could start with:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
d = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
\quad % horizontal spacing
dd = \begin{bmatrix} 4\\5\\6\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
ddd = \begin{bmatrix} 7\\8\\9\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]